# C++ How to new line without chopping words

Tags: c++

I am currently making a text game in c++. I am using a function that prints text one character at the time (to give a "narration" effect), which also goes to a new line to some condition defined by the function.

Here is the function:

```
void smart_print(const std::string& str, int spacer)//str is the printed message. spacer is the amount of space you want at the beginning and at the end of the cmd window
{
    int max = Console::BufferWidth - (spacer * 2);
    int limit = max;

    ut.spacer(5);//this prints 5 spaces

    for (int i = 0; i != str.size(); ++i)//this loop prints one character of the string every 50 milliseconds. It also checks if the limit is exceeded. If so, print new line
    {
        if (limit < 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
            ut.spacer(5);
            limit = max;
        }

        limit--;
        std::cout << str[i];
        Sleep(50);
    }   
}
```

The problem with this function, is that it chops the words, because it does a new line everytime the "limit" variable is less than 0, regardless if there is an incomplete word or not.

I made a sort of scheme to try to figure out how it should work correctly, but i can't manage to "translate" it into code.

1) Analyze the string, and check how long is the first word

2) Count the characters and stop counting when there is a space

3) Calculate if it can print the word (by subtracting the number of letters to max)

4) If the limit is exceeded, go to new line. Otherwise proceed to print the word one letter at the time

I really can't manage to make such function. I hope someone can help me out :P
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my answer did solve your problem, please don't forget to upvote and/or accept it as the answer for your question!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like checking if the current character is blank, using the [`std::isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) method like this:

```
// inside your for
if (limit < 0 && isspace(str[i]))
{
  cout << endl;
  ut.spacer(5);
  limit = max;
}

limit--;
if(!isspace(str[i])) std::cout << str[i];
Sleep(50);
```

**Note:** I haven't tested the code so I am not 100% sure if it works correctly.